# What happened to the manga "Me and the Devil Blues"?

Tags: me-and-the-devil-blues

What happened to the manga "Me and the Devil Blues" by Hiramoto Akira?

On MAL there's no finish date, but it looks like there hasn't been a new chapter in years.

Also, the author has since started a new work.

Did it end? Go on hiatus? Or get cancelled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ja.Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BF%BA%E3%81%A8%E6%82%AA%E9%AD%94%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA) about the series, the series had frequent hiatus half-way into the serialization, and it finally got discontinued in April issue in 2008.

Later in September 2010 issue of [Monthly Shounen Sirius](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88%E5%88%8A%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B9), in the introduction text to [Ago Nashi Gen to Ore Monogatari](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=22539) 『アゴなしゲンとNEMESIS物語』, a new series by the same author, it said that the author was aiming to reach the end of part 1 of OreAku (the shortened name of the series in Japan).

In 2014, it was announced that the series would resume serialization. And in the issue of [Young Magazine 3rd](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89) which was released on September 5th 2014, 2 chapters of OreAku which were not collected into tankoubon was released, and it was also announced that the 5th volume will be the last volume of the series.

The paragraph on Wikipedia which I take the information from (I don't translate everything here, only the main events):

> ### 連載中断と再開
>
> 連載途中から頻繁に休載するようになり、2008年4月号を最後に中断した。同年6月号を最後に、巻末にも「『俺と悪魔のブルーズ』は休載いたします」といった文言が掲載されなくなったことから、事実上打ち切り状態になった。 その後、同社『月刊少年シリウス』2010年9月号の同作者『アゴなしゲンとNEMESIS物語』の冒頭において、「現在、平本アキラ氏は『俺悪』の第1部・完を目指し描きだめ中なのです!」という作者近況の一文があり、水面下で執筆が進められているものと見られていた。
>
> そして2014年、同社『ヤングマガジンサード』創刊号にて正式に連載再開が決定した]。9月5日に発売された同号においては単行本未収録分が2話掲載されており、Vol.5から完全新作が最終章として発表されると告知された。